# How to excute a php file using AWS(Amazon Web Services)?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm trying excute this php file which contains this code :

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   
ini_set('display_errors','off');                

echo "OK!";

?>
```

The problem is that when I open his link, It proposes me to download the file. I just want get page with "ok!"...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have Apache and PHP setup on your EC2 instance? Turn error reporting on.

Comment: Is the filename extention .php? Are you using a ec2 instance or a bucket? Is php installed in the instance? Please provide more info.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hello, How can I setup Apache and PHP on my EC2 instance ?

Comment: That is way too broad @Saad. If you do not know how to setup a webserver on your Amazon instance you need to take some tutorials.

Comment: @andross I'm very beginner with AWS, all what I have did is : upload the php file with the index.html after choosing "Host a static website"

Comment: @JayBlanchard please, can you give me link ?

Comment: http://www.google.com

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Lol. That link was super helpful :D

Comment: Amazon S3 hosting which you are currently using does not support PHP. It is only designed for static (HTML+CSS) pages. At most, you can add some JavaScripts to such a site. What you want is to run your own EC2 instance (Linux or Windows - your choice) and install Apache+PHP stack on it. How to do it depends on the OS you choose and in case of Linux, on the distribution. In Debian based distros what you need is to run `sudo  apt install apache2 php` and you will be able to serve PHP files. Please note that you pay for the **time** your EC2 instance is running, which can generate costs.

Comment: Yes, thank you I have foud this tutorial and it works! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Y9QAI_MMsU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confusing Amazon S3 Static Web Hosting with an Application Server Web Hosting.

If you wish to execute PHP applications in AWS you will need to create an EC2 instance to execute the application and act as a web server.

Amazon S3 will only serve a static website, as such when you request a .php file from S3 it correctly serves the file as a regular file download to the requesting user.

Comment: Yes, thank you I have foud this tutorial and it works! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Y9QAI_MMsU